# Scrolling lag with SemanticZoom control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, semantic-zoom

I have used the SemanticZoom control in order to display about 350 items and I have grouped them using the initial letter of the name. The items do not have a lot of information actually they have only text so that it will be as light as possible.

The application works fine because it loads the data very fast and display them properly without any delay. My problem is that when I try to scroll right or left there is a big lag and the scrolling is not smooth.

What should I do in order to optimize the performance of scrolling in order to work properly? I have an i7 processor so I suppose that it will be worst in an older pc.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the VirtualizingStackPanel in the ItemsPanel with a normal StackPanel.